# java API response with error

Tags: java, response

I have a requirement to design a base response class for Java APIs. The response class contains 2 fields - a status (String) and a list of errors (List). 
Additionally, I need to do the following
The error should be a base class, there will be specific use cases that will have to create it's own error class extending this base error class (BaseError)

In order to do this, I have created the following class.
Is this the best way to go about doing this? I had to use a generic T because I cannot substitute a list of subtype of error into a list of type of the base error.

Please advise.

```
public class BaseResponse <T extends BaseError> {

    protected String status;
    protected List<T> errorList = new ArrayList<T>();

        public List<T> getErrorList() {
            return errorList;
        }

        public void setErrorList(List<T> errorList) {
            this.errorList = errorList;
        }

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void addError(T error) {
            this.errorList.add(error);
        }


}
```

Comment: Yest I think this is good. But you should add constructor to set status, I see no set method for status

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this class as a generic class you need to define default constructor and parametrized constructor.

**Please look this code:-**

```
public class BaseResponse <T extends BaseError> {

    protected String status;
    protected List<T> errorList = new ArrayList<T>();

    public BaseResponse(final String status) {
        this(status,"200");
    }

    public BaseResponse(final String status, final List<T> errorList) {
        super();
        this.status = status;
        this.errorList = errorList;
    }

    public List<T> getErrorList() {
        return errorList;
    }

    public void setErrorList(List<T> errorList) {
        this.errorList = errorList;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void addError(T error) {
        this.errorList.add(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.